# Laravel LdapRecord - Authenticating against database not Active Directory

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to implement LdapRecord and it is not going well. I followed the instructions but it appears that laravel is trying to use the database instead of the AD to look for the user before testing the credentials. I get an error message "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `mail` = stafftest@example.vic.edu.au limit 1)"
The 'mail' comes from the LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'mail' => $request->email,        //get('email')
            'password' => $request->password, //get('password')
        ];
    }
}
```

ldap.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default LDAP Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the LDAP connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all LDAP operations. Of
    | course you may add as many connections you'd like below.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('LDAP_CONNECTION', 'default'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | LDAP Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Below you may configure each LDAP connection your application requires
    | access to. Be sure to include a valid base DN - otherwise you may
    | not receive any results when performing LDAP search operations.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'default' => [
            'hosts' => [env('LDAP_HOST', '1234cdc01.curric.example.wan')],
            'username' => env('LDAP_USERNAME', 'examplebind'),
            'password' => env('LDAP_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'port' => env('LDAP_PORT', 389),
            'base_dn' => env('LDAP_BASE_DN', 'dc=curric,dc=example,dc=wan'),
            'timeout' => env('LDAP_TIMEOUT', 5),
            'use_ssl' => env('LDAP_SSL', false),
            'use_tls' => env('LDAP_TLS', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | LDAP Logging
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When LDAP logging is enabled, all LDAP search and authentication
    | operations are logged using the default application logging
    | driver. This can assist in debugging issues and more.
    |
    */

    'logging' => env('LDAP_LOGGING', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | LDAP Cache
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | LDAP caching enables the ability of caching search results using the
    | query builder. This is great for running expensive operations that
    | may take many seconds to complete, such as a pagination request.
    |
    */

    'cache' => [
        'enabled' => env('LDAP_CACHE', false),
        'driver' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
    ],

];
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'ldap' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,   //OpenLDAP
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                'sync_passwords' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'name' => 'cn',
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    'username' => 'samaccountname',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

So I am missing something somewhere. There must be some setting somewhere that tell the app to search the AD for the user not the database. Not sure where. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant but might be useful to others. You get a "Column not found" error because your auth.php file still refers to the 'users' provider instead of the 'ldap' provider. You did setup the 'ldap' provider so you just need to use it!
Change

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

To:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'ldap',
    ],
],
```

And it should work.